# Is hitting the Blast Cone faster than Walking?

Tags: league-of-legends

When walking through the Jungle, does hitting the exploding plant (Blast Cone) make you run faster through the jungle than just walking past it?

I'm not speaking about having a speed buff or something like that. It's more does by the time I land from turning around and hitting the plant would I be further by just walking?

Comment: Note that, unlike Dota, League doesn't have turn rates (characters turn instantly). The only time you lose is the time it takes from when you start the attack animation until the plant explodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it depends on your movespeed and a few other things, in general yes, using the blast cone is faster than running. This is especially true if you use the blast cone to travel over a wall. Unless you have a very large amount of movement speed, you will not be able to walk around the wall in the amount of time it takes to blast over the wall.